# Can anyone guide how to start date from starting point? I want to plot dates from 2003 to 2016 by one year gap

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
setwd("filechoose()")
Data<-read_xlsx("ggplot-UIB-graphs.xlsx")

h=ggplot(Data, aes(x=as.Date(Data$months), y=Data$`Avg-TWS Upper-IB CSR-JPL-GFZ mm`,group=1, xaxt='n', las=2))+ 
  geom_ribbon(aes (ymin=Data$STDL,ymax=Data$STDU),fill="grey")+ 
  geom_line(aes(y=Data$`Avg-TWS Upper-IB CSR-JPL-GFZ mm`), size=0.5)+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 years',labels = date_format('%b-%y'))
h=h+geom_smooth(method=lm,se=F,size= 1,color="red")
h=h+geom_line(aes(y=Data$`Avg-TWS Upper-IB CSR-JPL-GFZ mm`,colour= "Avg TWSA"), size=0.5)
h=h+geom_line(aes(y=Data$`Upper-IB GLDAS mm` ,colour= "GLDAS SMS+SWE+Qs+CWS"), size=1)
h=h+geom_line(aes(y=Data$`GWS mm` ,colour= "GWS"),  size=1)
plot(h)
```

[image]

Comment: As a general remark: it is often bad practice to use the `$` subsetting operator inside `aes()` statements. Also, I don't understand your question. Do you want the x-axis to start from 2003 and end at 2016? How does the one year gaps fit into that?

Comment: yes i want to start from 2003 and end at 2016. but you see the starting date gap? the plotting lines not starting from y-axis.

Comment: Right, I see. You could control that by setting the `expand` argument on the x-axis, e.g: `scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 years',labels = date_format('%b-%y'), expand = c(0,0))`

Comment: thank you so much it worked. Can you please further tell me how to control/change y-axis limit? in my posted picture there is gap by 200 between values. i want to control it.

Comment: That would probably work with `+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(my_lower_limit, my_upper_limit))`. You can also set an `expand` argument to control the amount of whitespace.

Comment: h=h+scale_y_continuous(limits =c(-200,150)), you mean like this? but this could not make any difference.